# Proof of equivalence well defined function

Tags: proof-explanation, curves, parametrization

This is the definition:

**Definition 1:**

A function $f:D\subseteq R\to R^n$ is said to be continuously differentiable of a $C^1$ function, if f is differentiable and the first derivative of f is continuous.

**Definition 2:**

A curve C in $R^n$ is smooth simple arc if C has a 1-1 $C^1$ parametrization of the form $f:[a,b] \to R^n$, the points f(a) and f(b) are then called the end points of the arc$

**Now comes the theorem:**

Let C be a smooth simple arc in $R^n$ simply parametrised by a smooth 1-1 function, $f:[a,b]\subseteq R\to R^n $ Then any smooth parametrisation $h:[c,d]\subseteq R\to R^n$ of C is 1-1 and is equivalent to f.

Now as the definition of equivalent is not what I am wondering about so I am not going to post it. My question is simply with regards to how the proof starts:

It starts as follows:

**Proof**

The function $\Phi=f^{-1}\circ h$ is well defined and maps $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]$ and satisfies $h=f\circ\Phi$.

Now if are okey with this I understand the how the proves follow, however, I am getting stuck with the part where they state that $\Phi$ is well defined.

**Question**

1) Why is $\Phi$ well defined?

2) Why does it satisfy $h=f\circ\Phi$

Comment: It is well defined since  $h $ and $f^{-1}$ are. The equality in (2) follows from its definition.

Comment: So if f is one to one it follows that $f^{-1}$ is well defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is well defined because $f$ is one-to-one and therefore $f^{-1}$ exists as a map from $f\bigl([a,b]\bigr)\bigl(=h\bigl([a,b]\bigr)\bigr)$ into $\mathbb R$ and because $h\bigl([a,b]\bigr)\subset D_{f^{-1}}$.
2. Because $\Phi= f^{-1}\circ h\implies f\circ\Phi=f\circ(f^{-1}\circ h)=h$.

Comment: Could you clarify the notation in 1. I don't get all the parenthesis.

Comment: I'm just saying that $f\bigl([a,b]\bigr)=h\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ and that $h$ maps $[a,b]$ into a subset of the domain of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Okey, I am going to have to think  about it a bit more before I accept.

Comment: I am not sure I understand is $ h(p)$ not equal to $f(\Phi(p))$

Comment: But $h(p)$ **is** equal to $f\bigl(\Phi(p)\bigr)$, for each $p\in[a,b]$.

Comment: does it follow that if f is 1-1 then $f^{-1}$ is well defined?

Comment: Yes: $f^{-1}$ is a map from $f\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: hopefully last question , if $f^{-1}$ is well defined does it imply that it it is 1-1 , or is that the definition of well defined?

Comment: An inverse function is *always* one-to-one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86376/discussion-between-alexander-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Comment: would you mind having a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018528/inverse-function-being-onto