# Inverse function being onto.

Tags: proof-explanation, multilinear-algebra

Please refer to this [follow up on a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018347/proof-of-equivalence-well-defined-function/3018362?noredirect=1#3018347).

As you can see from that link:

$\Phi=f^{-1}\circ h$ is well defined and maps $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]$ now in my textbook the next theorem following what I posted in the link, is as follows:

**Theorem 2**
Let $f:[a,b]\subseteq R\to R^n$ and $h:[c,d]\subseteq R\to R^n$ be 1-1 parametrizations of a simple arc C in $R^n$ Then there exists a unique function $\Phi$ from [a,b] onto [c,d] such that $h=f\circ\Phi$. Moreover, $\Phi$ is continuous and strictly monotonic.

Now I am getting confused as the proof provided for theorem 2 is the theorem provided in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018347/proof-of-equivalence-well-defined-function/3018362?noredirect=1#3018347) but in the follow up question $\Phi$ maps [c,d] onto [a,b] and not opposite. What am I missing?

To be more specific the proof states:

By Theorem 1 ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018347/proof-of-equivalence-well-defined-function/3018362?noredirect=1#3018347)) the function $\Phi$ is 1-1, continuous and strictly monotonic.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos would you mind having a look?

Comment: $\phi$ should map $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]. h$ is defined on $[c,d]$, and $f$ is defined over $[a,b]$, so $\phi: [c,d]\rightarrow[a,b], \phi(t)=\frac{a-b}{c-d}t+\frac{bc-ad}{c-d}$

Comment: I suppose that you have spotted an error on your textbook.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri How does it work in the case where [c,d] is mapped into a subset of R^n, that does not span entire R^n, then even if $\Phi$ is one to one it would only map [c,d] onto a subset of [a,b] would it still be classified as onto?

Comment: Note that it is generally not true that a curve will span the entire codomain $\mathbb R^n$. When we talk about the invertibility of $f$, we are talking about $f$ being surjective on its range, $f([a,b])$, which is always true. Also, since  $\phi$ maps $[c,d]$ onto $[a,b]$, the range of $f$ and $h=f\circ\phi$ is identical. So, the case of $f$ and $h$ having different ranges doesn't arise.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thanks this is great. Also could I draw the conclusion that both have same range since both f and h are smooth parametrisation of the arc C it follows that they have the same range and since $f^{-1}$  is 1 to 1 maps it back to [a,b]?

Comment: That is true. Their range is the curve $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  to be more specific apart from just believing the comment in the book that $/phi$ maps [c,d] onto [a,b] I want to be sure that that is the case hence from the link to the previous question what would tell me that h and f have same range is it simply that both h and f are a parametrisation if arc C?

Comment: That is one way of seeing it. You could also say that every point in $[a,b]$ is the image of some point in $[c,d]$ under $\phi$ i.e. $R(\phi)=\phi([c,d])=[a,b]$, so the range of $h=h([c,d])=f(\phi([c,d]))=f([a,b])=R(f)$, the range of $f$.